# ERROR: Failure processing PNG image in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have saved my images in `res/drawable` folder but still it is giving me this error on console

```
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] libpng error: Not a PNG file
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] ERROR: Failure processing PNG image D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\drawable-ldpi\ic_launcher.png
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] libpng error: Not a PNG file
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] ERROR: Failure processing PNG image D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\aboutus.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/about').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\autofare.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/auto').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\busroutes.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/bus').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\busroutes.xml:63: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/right').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\busroutes.xml:72: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/cancel').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\firstscreenactivity.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/mumbai1').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\listviewofwesternavailabletrains.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/cell3').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\main.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/first').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\mumbaihelpline.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/helpline').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\selectambulance.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/ambu').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\selectedwesterntraindetails.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/list6').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\selecthospital.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/hospital').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\selectservicelistview.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/cell1').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\selecttrainline.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/curv').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\taxifare.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/taxi').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\westernavailabletrains.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/list5').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\westernavailabletrains.xml:18: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/cell3').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\youareatcentral.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/local').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\youareatcentral.xml:70: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/right').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\youareatcentral.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/cancel').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\youareatharbour.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/local').
[2012-04-28 18:36:46 - Local] D:\Android2_worksapce\Local\res\layout\youareatharbour.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/right').
```

I have saved the images (in png format) in resources, but it is giving me an error stating that it's not png file. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Upload that image somewhere. I think the image is not a png file or it is corrupted.

Comment: i have saved file in png formate

Comment: It's res/drawable not resource/drawable (see line 1 of your question).

Comment: no its actually res/drawable folder

Comment: One error I ran into with images is that certain names are offlimits. Try renaming it and see if it will work then. Don't forget you will need to clean the project after the rename.

Comment: no it is not working after renaming it...

Comment: guys if u know the solution plz tell me.......

Comment: Rahul you must hav placed all images at one time so you cannot figure out which image is causing problem , do one thing put images in drawable folder one by one there must be few images which are corrupt and  will cause problem when added

Answer (score 7):

One Easy but time consuming solution...
Try opening your png in mspaint and do save As. this issue will resolve..
i dont know why we need to do this.. but somehow its working for me...

Comment: But if we do that, then the image loses it's transparency.... how do we fix that?

Comment: For those who don't want to lose transparency by using MS Paint, you can open your PNG in online tools like https://www.sumopaint.com/ and re-save as PNG. Doing this removed these errors in my build and kept transparency

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://www.pawanagarwal.com/2011/07/on-android-ecplise-ide-libpng-error-not-a-png-file/) link for reference

Android does support 24-bit and 32-bit,
but it has some problem with **ADOBE PHOTOSHOP**'s PNG files.
So the solution is to open in MS Paint and save again as Kalpesh Patel said.

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 1):

This is because of any jpg file is mistakenly converted to a png file. If you have added any images in drawable folder (asset folder) then make sure that all images extension should be png means do not change extension jpg to png. If you want to convert jpg to png then use online tool or editor to convert.

The issue is if image is not converted properly to PNG then when you run then it will give this error.

**Solution: 1st do you added any images recently in a drawable folder? if yes then check all images extension should proper (i mean do not forcefully add png extension).**

or

**2nd if you not sure which image extension is not proper then you should have to edit all png images in the editor or online tool and save again into png file by this issue will get solved for sure.**

I have spend 3 hours on this to figure out and i come up with this solution. It was my mistake i have edited jpg image to png but it is not properly converted to png so thats why it was giving me error. After i pick that image and properly converted to png file then it work for me!